# ASP.NET MVC 2 - Validation of Radiobutton

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I validate a radiobutton in asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally one value is made selected by default. In case No value is selected by default, this link may help
[ASP.NET MVC Html.RadioButton Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722655/asp-net-mvc-html-radiobutton-exception)

Comment: So good so far.. that were a huge help :) - Now the next problem is that I'm using PRG pattern (Post-Redirect-Get) - Which dosent allow me to do return View() because it will break the pattern.. Is there anyhow I can work around it and use a redirectToAction or I'm bound to use return view() ?

Comment: @user407674 - You could use client-side validation.